# JQuery selector - full or optimized scan?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code example:

```
$JK("body *").each(function() { ... });
```

Will JQuery fill the elements' array first before calling `each()` or there is kinda `LINQ`-style optimization, so that `function` will be called during the DOM tree traversal? I guess that this optimization might (or not) be deployed into the JS engine. If so, how one can know if it is implemented for this or that engine/browser?

Comment: Just to clarify: how the selector here is evaluated is entirely irrelevant to your question, correct?

Comment: I don't think you can intercept each time a single element is fetched from the DOM. Native functions will also just return a (sort of) array with all matched elements in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It builds the entire list first. I can't imagine how it could be done in the browser/JavaScript engine, though I *guess* it might be possible to make NodeList be lazy somehow.

The jQuery object looks like an Array instance (it isn't, but it tries to look like one), meaning that you can randomly-access elements by numeric index.  It'd be quite a trick to make that be lazy.

Note that modern browsers support DOM-accessing functions that push a lot of the work down into the browser's internals, so that often — as, I suspect, in the case of your selector, which is really just

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getElementsByTagName('*')
```

the browser hands back the complete list to jQuery. That's why I mentioned making the NodeList object be lazy, but I still think it'd be pretty hard given the semantics of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It fills the elements array first.

Since this is really just javascript and javascript is single threaded (except for web workers which are not being used here and can't access the DOM anyway), it happens like this:

This function call is executed to completion:

```
$JK("body *")
```

That function returns a jQuery object upon with the

```
.each()
```

method is called.  In that method, it iterates through the array of DOM elements and calls the callback function once for each DOM element.

Comment: It is interesting to think, however, about how a lazy API like jQuery could be done. It'd be pretty challenging.

Comment: @Pointy - It would be quite challenging.  All access to the internal DOM array (even internal to jQuery) would have to go through an accessor that would fill it as needed before access.  Any operation that needed all the DOM objects would not get faster end-to-end (in fact, it would probably be slower).  Also could be some sequencing issues with chained methods where subsequent methods called on the first DOM elements mess up the ability to traverse the DOM to fetch the reminaing DOM elements.  Unsure how much benefit would even be achieved if problems were surmounted.